# implicit differentiation contradiction?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

As we know, for implicit differentiation we have
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$

but if I use a trick that  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial F}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ as $\partial F$ cancels each other out, so it is like $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{F_x}{F_y}$ without the "minus", where did I go wrong?

Comment: What is $~F_x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case of "differentials are not fractions" and is a marked downside of Leibniz notation. While the notation $\frac{d y}{d x }$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ looks like a fraction, we can't simply "cancel the $\partial F$" out. In effect, you have just proved a difference between differentials and fractions.

For another, consider the chain rule in several variables. Let $F= F(x,y)$ and let $x=x(s,t)$ and $y=y(s,t)$. Then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

If we were allowed to cancel terms like you suggest, then we would have that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 2 \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$, which is clearly not true.